# Bash keyboard shortcut to add comment character (#) to beginning of command line

Tags: bash, keyboard, shortcut

When using Mac OS X including iTerm, I can simply press
<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>$</kbd> and the line in bash that I am currently tiping will get a `#` added to the beginning and the line returns. I like this very much as it prevents from actually executing that command while still editing it and I don't have to jump to the beginning of the line to insert that `#` character there.
However, when I log onto our cluster, this functionality is lost. I tried to search for this feature but only found posts about using sed etc. so suggestions which are not for the interactive kind of using bash that I am referring to.

Could somebody please point me to a resource where this functionality is explained (bash-guide?) so I could look up how to make it work when logging in to other machines? Or is this something Mac/iTerm-specific? But then, I would expect it to work also on our cluster, as long as I use my machine of course.

Comment: It would not answer your question for a `command` but you can use `Ctrl + A` to go to the start of the line, insert `#` manually, and then press `Ctrl + E` to reach the end of the line

Comment: It probably depends on your vi/emacs settings and the shell.  `set -o vi` uses vi command-line editing (default with korn shell), `set -o emacs` is the bash default(as @Incognito's comment).  Type `set -o` to see your settings.

Comment: @Incognito: While you are right that this would work and I use it usually when navigating around the command-line, it is indeed not what I was looking for. But this hint could be interesting for others.

Comment: @Shadow Yup, I know this is not the answer to your question :) and I am looking forward to an answer, as it will be of a real help!

Comment: @cdarke: They are the same on the cluster as well as locally. Interesting information anyhow. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[This might work for you](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Miscellaneous-Commands)

See `insert-comment (M-#)`